# WHM Backup Script - Compress Directories

Tags: shell, centos, whm

I am on a CentOS 6 using WHM and Cpanel.  I have my backups set to run daily but I get all the raw files and directories.  I want to send all of this to AWS S3, and have a script to do all that, but need to send 1 compressed file instead of all the raw files.  I want to create a script that will zip up all the directories into separate .tar.gz files, then zip all them up into 1 file with the date in the name.  Here is the script I am using, and it seems to work ok, but there are a few problems I can't figure out.

```
for dir in /backup/cpbackup/daily/*/
do
  base=$(basename "$dir")
  if [ "$dir" == "azureat" ]; then
    tar --exclude='homedir/public_ftp' --exclude='homedir/svn_sync' --exclude='homedir/backup-*.tar.gz' -cvzf "${base}.tar.gz" "$dir" >> backup.log
  else
    tar --exclude='homedir/public_ftp' --exclude='homedir/backup-*.tar.gz' -cvzf "${base}.tar.gz" "$dir" >> backup.log
  fi
  rm -rf "$dir"
done
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
tar -cvzf WHM_Daily_Backup_$now.tar.gz *.tar.gz >> backup.log
mv WHM_Daily_Backup_$now.tar.gz /backup/aws_s3 >> backup.log
```

The problem is that when the script is ran, I get an extra .tar.gz file called *.tar.gz that doesn't contain anything, and the last file doesn't print the date.  It looks like WHM_Daily_Back_.tar.gz.  I am kinda new to this type of scripting and I am stuck.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem was I should not have used spaces when making a variable. So now = $(date +"%m_%d_%Y") needed to be now=(date +"%m_%d_%Y").  Thanks anyway, and hope the script is helpful to others!

Answer (score 0):

Backup to Amazon S3 is supported natively by WHM starting with version 11.42. So you don't need a custom script anymore :

> Using Amazon S3 as a backup destination is a feature of cPanel & WHM version 11.42. We released the production version of 11.42 on Jan 28, 2014. It is currently deployed to EDGE and CURRENT.

Source : http://features.cpanel.net/responses/amazon-s3-integrated-into-whm-as-a-backup-option